# Azure Automation Account runbook error while remove/add user role on the storage account

Tags: azure, azure-runbook

When i'm trying to remove user on the storage account using below commands through automation account i'm getting error

> object reference not set to instance of an object

```
Remove-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName $emailid -RoleDefinitionName 
"Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor" -Scope "/subscriptions/00000-0000-00/resourceGroups/resourcegroupname/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageaccname"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Few of the workaround you can follow to achieve the above requirement;

- Make sure that you have following [**`permission`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-role-based-access-control) to that subscription
  `Owner` or, `User Access Administrator`( `must have a role that includes Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write permissions`) to assign or remove.
- If you have above permission Check the role which have defined in storage account same as what you have mentioned want to remove. Or it exist or not.
- And make sure that the role which you want to remove, that not showing as ***inherited*** If so you can not remove those assignments as you are trying to remove a role assignment at a child scope.

For more information please refer the below links:-

- ***MICROSOFT DOCUMENT***| [***Remove Azure role Assignments***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-remove) ,[***Manage role permissions and security in Automation***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-role-based-access-control) & [***Remove-AzRoleAssignment***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/remove-azroleassignment?view=azps-7.5.0)